# checking stored variable with scanf

Tags: c, char, int, scanf, unsigned

I am wondering why is it that regardless if I input a digit or a letter or a character it keeps printing the last print line, how come the yes "This is an integer line never work? How do I go about getting the user to only input a positive digit?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <limits.h>

  main(){
  unsigned int num;
  printf("Please input a positive number: ");

  scanf("%d",&num);
  if ((num >= 'a' && num <= 'z') || (num >='A' && num <= 'Z')){
    printf("not an interger(alpha)");
  }
  else if ( num >= '0' && num <= '9'){
    printf("yes this is an integer");
  }
  else{
    printf("not an integer");

  }
}
```

Comment: by the way, the main() should have a int return type.

Comment: @jfly - It is C - void is possible

Comment: @EdHeal For C99, the int return type may not be omitted.
You may omit the return statement from main. If you do, and main finished, there is an implicit return 0. I think it should probably be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the types of your variables right. An `unsigned int` can only ever be that: an non-negative integer. You cannot look at the first character in an integer.

Your program analyses a string, i.e. an array of characters, even if it only looks at the first letter. Therefore, your data must be an array of characters. This also means that you need to scan for a string with `"%s"`.

When you test the first character of your string, you must use an array index, `str[0]`.

To put all this together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[20];

    printf("Please input a positive number: ");
    scanf("%19s", str);

    if ((str[0] >= 'a' && str[0] <= 'z') || (str[0] >='A' && str[0] <= 'Z')) {
        printf("alpha\n");
    } else if (str[0] >= '0' && str[0] <= '9') {
        printf("integer\n");
    } else {
        printf("other\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**: As pointed out, this code does not check whether a string repesents a decimal number. It only checks the first character. A full solution should check all characters and is left as an exercise to the original poster.

My impression is that the OP has difficulties to distinguish between the data types, so I tried to focus on that.

I've also added a field width to the `scanf` to avoid buffer overflow. I'm not going into the details of `sscanf` here, because I think that the OP still has to understand more of the very basic stuff.

Comment: Still not quite right. Type in '0hhhhh' Will say it is an integer. Do not get me started if you type over19 characters

Comment: @EdHeal: Of course the code is not a complete check whether the input represents a decimal or not. It is based on the OP's example. And you are easily annoyed, aren't you if I "get you stared" by omitting the string width in a piece of throwaway code. Don't you - and the other posters here, for that matter - see that the OP has problems to grasp the concept of strings and integers as different data types? My answer was intended to point the OP in the right direction.

Comment: "Don't get me started.." is an English euphemism

Comment: Obviously I'm not a native speaker of English, but I think I know what "don't get me started" means. Well, I thought I knew what it means, maybe I need to be more careful. Never mind.

Comment: Only the English can speak it properly - or so we are lead to believe :-> (PS: Get an American to pronounce Worcestershire)

Comment: @EdHeal: The bad representation of a word's pronunciation in written English is a topic of its own - don't get me started. :-)

Answer (score 3):

change `else if ( num >= '0' && num <= '9')` to `else if ( num >= 0 && num <= 9)`, assume you input a number between 0 and 9.

Comment: Try typing in 65 into that code. It would report the wrong error

Comment: I know this problem, since a char is also a int in C. I just point out why the OP can't get what he expected.

Comment: The fundamental problem is comparing two different things

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing against int in second if.
Depending upon your need, change it to  (i.e. remove ' ')

(num >= 0)

or

else if ( num >= 0 && num <= 9)

Answer (score 0):

This code is incorrect. Please check out the manual page for `scanf` http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

You need `scanf("%c", &character_var`); and call it repeatedly. Alternatively read a string

**EDIT**

```
if (scanf("%u", &num) == 1) {
   printf("Well done - you managed to type in a positive integer %u\n", num);
} else {
   printf("Have another go!\n");
}
```

Is a solution

Comment: but the variable is unsigned int it meant to hold digit 0 and greater.. ?

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII of '0' is 48. and '9' is 48+9.
so `else if ( num >= '0' && num <= '9')` will be true if you input a value between 48 and 57.

The solution is, as jfly said, change to `else if ( num >= 0 && num <= 9).`

Comment: Then you have to use %s instead of %d in scanf("%d",&num); and the num should be a character array.

Comment: this solution only work for number between 0 and 9 not number that are greater then 9

Comment: Yes. So you have to scan it as a string and use some easy custom functions to check whether it is an integer. You may use built in functions like isdigit.